# Pandas column expressions with if else

Tags: string, python-2.7, pandas, concatenation

I am creating a string expression in Python `pandas` in this manner

```
df['ABC'] = (df['A']
                  + ' + ' + df['B']
                  + ' + ' + df['C'])
```

However, `pandas` returns this error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

The data frame has `NaN` for a few column and the string concatenation fails for these cases. How can I write a statement to achieve the concatenation as shown below for a test case. It seems like we have to add an ifelse statement within the expression above:

```
A   B   C   ABC
x           x
x   y       x + y
x   y   z   x + y + z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> join_row = lambda ts: ' + '.join(ts.dropna())
>>> df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(join_row, axis=1)
0            x
1        x + y
2    x + y + z
dtype: object
```

`[['A', 'B', 'C']]` is necessary only if there are other columns in the data-frame.